# Highchart export server prevent 0 value in the pdf

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am using highchart export server for exporting the highchart as psd in itextsharp.

I have created a handler that will give me the highchart as png image this image is rendered into the itext pdf.

So my rendering is: Convert the highchart to image using json file that will  be used for rendering it into the pdf.

Expected:  http://jsfiddle.net/9owxLgm9/1/

The problem is I am not able to add the code that will prevent the rendering of 0 values in the highchart pdf

```
formatter: function () {
                    if (this.y != 0) {

                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 0) + ' %';
                    }
                },
```

so my pdf images render something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/9owxLgm9/2/
ie it also shows the 0 values.

Is there any way i can remove the 0 based values in the json file

[image: highChart in pdf shows a zero on label which i want to remove]

Comment: I'm not sure about your convert process, but maybe instead of removing labels, you could remove `0` value point **before** converting the chart?

Comment: I am removing the zero label in the highchart but while exporting the zero label is still visible as it is not getting removed in the pdf. I cannot remove the 0 values as the when the value is removed the corresponding value from the Legend also dissapear which I dont want to occour

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But your "expected" chart works, why can't you use this config? Maybe you should explain how you export the chart in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's really the result you want, but you can remove empty values / stats labels from the pie chart with this simple formatter:

```
formatter: function() {
  if (this.y != 0) {
    return this.y +'%';
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**[Your updated demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/9owxLgm9/4/)**.

The above code will output the percentages as label value, so if you want to keep the names as label, you simply need to replace `return this.y +'%';` by `return this.point.name;`

Here's **[another example](http://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/9owxLgm9/6/)** with names as label (also following your fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a formatter function

```
"pie": {
                "allowPointSelect": true,
                "cursor": "pointer",
                "dataLabels": {
                  "enabled": true,
                  "formatter": "function () {if (this.y != 0) { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 0) + ' %';} }",
                  "format": "{point.percentage:.2f} %",
                  "distance": 4,
                  "filter": { "property": "percentage",  "operator": ">",      "value": 1}
                },
                "showInLegend": true
            }
```